# Facebook JS SDK Can't logout

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, logout

I seem to be having a weird problem where if I call FB.logout, the app successfuly logs out and the status returns as `unknown`.
But when I refresh the page, the status returns as `connected` and I'm logged in.

```
    function facebookLogout() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('.not-logged-in').css({ "display": "inline-block" });
                    $('.logged-in').css({ "display": "none" });

                    // Not logged in
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please login.';

                    // UI
                    $('#account-options').slideDown();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

How I check for login status on page load:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'appId',
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
            // the session
            xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            account.facebookStatusChangeCallBack(response, function () {
                // Logged in
                facebookLogin();

                // Login to GameSparks and get player data
                account.gameSparksLogin(function (player) {
                    onGameSparksLogin(player, true);
                }, function (error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                });

                // UI
                $('#account-options').slideDown();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#account-options').slideUp();
                }, 2500);

            }, function () {
                // Not logged in
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please login.';

                // UI
                $('#account-options').slideDown();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#account-options').slideUp();
                }, 2500);

            });
        });
    };
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.
PS: I have also tried expiring the cookie (from console), but it just re-sets itself on page refresh.

Comment: That is what is _supposed_ to happen, when you use the JS SDK - it recognizes recurring users that have already logged in to your app before automatically. Only if the user was logged out not only from your app, but from Facebook as well, you could expect the JS SDK to *not* recognize them afterwards - until they log in to Facebook again.

Comment: Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: No, not really. Again, it is explicitly designed to work this way, because it is just more convenient for the majority of use cases.

Comment: But doesn't it make more sense to keep the user logged out, since they are explicitly logging out.

Comment: Well that’s something you would have to discuss with Facebook …

Comment: Fair enough. :)
Thank you very much for your help